# PHP/MySQL SELECT statement with 'variable' <> ' ' or 'variable' IS NOT NULL not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a SQL routine written that compares a user's input with an existing value in a table. If the value exists, a green check mark appears next to the input. If it doesn't, then a red x appears. My SQL statement is as follows:

```
      $check = $con->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM emaillist");
      $check->execute();
      $result = $check->fetchColumn(); //Get no. of columns
      $check = $con->prepare("SELECT Username FROM emaillist WHERE Username =                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
              '$Name' AND '$Name' <> '' ");
      $check->execute();
      $result = $check->fetchColumn(); //Get exact column
      if(!$result) {
               show red x } else { show green check }
```

This works fine as long as there is input. The red x appears when the input doesn't match and the green check appears when it does; however, I don't want *anything* to display if the field is left blank. Right now, the red x appears if the field is empty or is null. Using IS NOT NULL didn't work, either. What am I missing?

Comment: If $Name is coming from a user input then I think it would be better to check for its validity independent of the SQL query rather than putting it in the query itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rewriting your logic like this:

```
if ($Name != ''){
    $check = $con->prepare("SELECT Username FROM emaillist WHERE Username = '$Name'");
    $check->execute();
    $result = $check->fetchColumn(); //Get exact column
    if(!$result) {
          // show red x 
    } else { 
         // show green check 
    }
}
else {
    // show red here or some other input error message
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You only have two branches: show red x and show green check.  You need a third, e.g.

```
if (!$Name) {
    //show nothing
}
else if (!$result) {
    //show red x
}
else {
    //show green check
}
```

---

On an unrelated note, it's great that you're using `PDO` but you need to properly parameterize your queries to be safe from injection.

Comment: No worries. When this goes into production, we'll be using named placeholders. This is just a prototyping exercise. ;-)